# TAL removes every TAG

Tags: html, pyramid, markup, chameleon, tal

I'm using Chameleon in the Pyramids Framework and TAL. Unfortunately TAL removes every tag up to the first both.

HTML-Template:

```
<label tal:attributes="for item.id">
    <span i18n:translate="Because:" tal:condition="item.leading_because">Because:</span>
    <span tal:repeat="premise item.premises" tal:attributes="for item.id; id premise.id">
        <span tal:attributes="for item.id; id premise.id" tal:content="premise.title">premise</span>
        <span tal:condition="not:repeat.premise.end">
            <i><span i18n:translate="and"> and </span></i>
        </span>
    </span>
</label>
```

Rendered Example:

```
<li>
    <input type="radio" name="discussion-button-group" onclick="location.href=&quot;http://localhost:4284/d/cat-or-dog/r/11/undermine/29&quot;" id="11">
    <label for="11">
        Because: Cats are fluffy and Cats are small
    </label>
```

Now I'm missing all span-Tags in "Because ...", does somebody knows, why?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing and thoughts about the mysterious span- and label-tag, this will solve any problem:

```
<li tal:repeat="item items">
    <input type="radio" name="discussion-button-group" onclick="" tal:attributes="id item.id; onclick item.url">
    <label tal:attributes="for item.id" tal:condition="item.leading_because">
        <span tal:omit-tag="" tal:attributes="for item.id" i18n:translate="Because:">Because:</span>&nbsp;
    </label>
        <span tal:repeat="premise item.premises" tal:omit-tag="">
        <label tal:attributes="for item.id; id premise.id" tal:content="premise.title">premise</label>
    <label tal:condition="not:repeat.premise.end">&nbsp;<em i18n:translate="and">and</em>&nbsp;</label>
</span>
```

So I'll have an input tag filled with labels :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your closing  tags are messed up. You are not matching the pairs.

Comment: Nope, they match. It's just a wrong alignment here.